# How do i do calculations in Python Gtk?

Tags: python, pygtk

I'm currently working on a Calculator. I'm done with most of the stuff except the most important thing, the calculations. I just want to know if it's possible to solve my problem with such a code and if so, how? I tried everything i could but nothing is working. I'd really appreciate an answer.

This is some of my code:

I just copied the button16 because my code is long.

```
button16 = Gtk.Button(label="C")
    button16.connect("clicked", self.button16_clicked)
    vbox.pack_start(button16, True, True, 0)
    vbox.pack_end(button16, True, True, 0)
    self.add(button16)



    self.first_num = 0
    self.second_num = 0
    self.result = 0
    self.operation = ""




def button1_clicked(self, widget):
    self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str(1))

def button2_clicked(self, widget):
    self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str(2))

def button3_clicked(self, widget):
    self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str(3))

def button4_clicked(self, widget):
    self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str(4))

def button5_clicked(self, widget):
    self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str(5))

def button6_clicked(self, widget):
    self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str(6))

def button7_clicked(self,widget):
    self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str(7))

def button8_clicked(self,widget):
    self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str(8))

def button9_clicked(self,widget):
    self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str(9))

def button10_clicked(self,widget):
    self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str(0))

def button11_clicked(self,button11):
    self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str("+"))

def button12_clicked(self,widget):
    self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str("-"))

def button13_clicked(self,widget):
    self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str("*"))

def button14_clicked(self,widget):
    self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str("/"))

def button15_clicked(self, button15):
    self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str("="))

def button16_clicked(self,button16):
    self.entry.set_text("")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what You mean by "doing calculations in Gtk". Maybe you should simply pass arguments in event handling.

In this " button16.connect("clicked", self.button16_clicked)" after comma: ("clicked",button15_clicked, arg1, arg2)

And then def button15_clicked(self, button15, arg1, arg2): (...) mynumber=arg1+arg2.
 If You save numbers entered anywhere. ( (for example in button1 add line like a=a+str(1), in button"+,-,*,/" you leave a and take b instead and then pass a and b to "=")

And if not, You must take a final string in button15_clicked and split it to ministrings between +-*/(), do the math to get result and add run sth like self.show_result(result) from inside button15_clicked

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer but are those arg1 and arg2 for example the variables i declared earlier(first_num and second_num)?

Comment: Yes. I added example, You must only see what the values do to change them not only in functions ;) like: use "return a, b"

Comment: Sorry but i still do not understand the part in the middle where you say i leave a and take b instead...etc Code:                                                                                                                     def button1_clicked(self, widget,first_num):
        self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str(1))
        self.first_num += str(1)      How can i make this work? Sorry for the stupid question but i need to know how i can make it work specifically on my code.

Comment: For example: if you only pass to functions with numbers first_number but to function "+" You pass both: first_number and second_number, and do this: self.second_number+=first_number ...and... self.first_number="" , then you can add some things to empty string in first_number to get, say, 137 and pass both to "=" (or to "+" or sth else). I'm certain its not very elegant way, but should act.