# PyGTK calculator

Tags: python-3.x, pygtk

I want to make a calculator with Python GTK. I am trying to get a button to display my text in the application. However, my function gives me this error `TypeError: Calculator.clickedButton1() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. I know about self and arguments, but I have attempted a variable and passing `Gtk.Entry` into the function, but it doesn't work.

There was only one stackoverflow post that was similar but never solved. [How do i do calculations in Python Gtk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015529/how-do-i-do-calculations-in-python-gtk)

```
# this is what the application looks like simply.
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Calculator(Gtk.Window): # my sub class
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title="Calculator") # the base class Gtk.Window
        self.set_border_width(10)

        # the header and title bar
        headerBar = Gtk.HeaderBar()
        headerBar.set_show_close_button(True)
        headerBar.props.title = "Calculator"
        self.set_titlebar(headerBar)

        # this is my button and calling the function.
        self.button1 = Gtk.Button(label="1")
        self.button1.connect("clicked", self.clickedButton1)

        # creating the entry field
        self.entry = Gtk.Entry()
        self.entry.set_text("")

        # this creates the grid
        grid = Gtk.Grid()
        grid.add(self.button1)
        grid.attach_next_to(self.entry,self.button1,Gtk.PositionType.TOP,4,4)

        self.add(grid)

    # my function
    def clickedButton1():
        self.entry.set_text("1")
        return self.entry

# creating the actual window and running continuosly.
win = Calculator()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: "I know about self" but you didn't write `def clickedButton1(self):`

Comment: But self is implied in Python.

Comment: @mkrieger1 how did that work? Why did that work?

Comment: Methods must accept at least one argument which is typically called "self" and is passed implicitly when calling the method.

Comment: @mkrieger1, To make sure I understand what you are saying, there is an implied self, then there is the self for the object? There are two?

Comment: I'm not sure what your understanding is of an "implied self". Fact is, you have to define methods such that there is one parameter, typically named "self". When the method is called, the object is implicitly passed as argument for this "self" parameter. There are no "two self".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to pass self into the function. Apparently, the self is not implied like I believed. Credit goes to @mkrieger1.

```
    def clickedButton1(self, entry):
        text = self.entry.get_text()
        text += "1"
        self.entry.set_text(text)
```